# Checked checkbox using array response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have a form and it has 4 checkboxes. I am getting a response from the server and according to that response I need to checked that particular checkbox/s.

For example I have four checkboxes called 2100,2200,2300,2400

Then I am getting a array response from the server and array has 2200 and 2400.
Then I need to checked both 2200 and 2400 checkboxes.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "send_db.php",
    data: {'send_array':array_send},
    success:  function(data){

    var jsonRes  = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    var plant  = jsonRes.plant;
    var array_length = jsonRes.plant.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {

        document.getElementsByName("user_plant1").checked = true;

    }

    }
});
```

Here *plant* has the values.

These are my checkboxes...

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk21" name="user_plant1" value="2100">2100</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk22" name="user_plant1" value="2200">2200</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk23" name="user_plant1" value="2300">2300</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk24" name="user_plant1" value="2400">2400</label>
</div>
```

Comment: [**getElementsByName();**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a node list - collection/group of elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
var chkData = "2200,2400";
chkData = chkData.split(',');

var el=document.querySelectorAll('input[name=user_plant1]');
el.forEach(function(chk){
  if(chkData.includes(chk.value)){
    chk.setAttribute('checked',true);
  }
  else{
    chk.checked = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk21" name="user_plant1" value="2100">2100</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk22" name="user_plant1" value="2200">2200</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk23" name="user_plant1" value="2300">2300</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" id="chk24" name="user_plant1" value="2400">2400</label>
</div>
```

Comment: u saved my day, works really fine. I changed *'input[type=checkbox]'* to *"input[name='user_plant1']"* for my need. thank you

Comment: @D.Madu, you are most welcome. I have updated the answer as well.....thanks

Comment: one another thing. if i checked 4 checkboxes from first response and again take a response with two checkboxes, other two not unchecked. I tried with

**if(chkData.includes(chk.value)){**
**chk.setAttribute('checked',true);**
      **}else{**
**chk.setAttribute('checked',false);**
**}**

and try to flase all checkboxes at the top like this.

 **document.getElementById("chk21").checked = false;**
 **document.getElementById("chk22").checked = false;**
 **document.getElementById("chk23").checked = false;**
 **document.getElementById("chk24").checked = false;**

both not working

Comment: Do you want to set the other check boxes unchecked on the second response?

Comment: yes. for example first time 2100,2200,2300,2400 come and checked all boxes, second time only come 2100,2200. but 2300 and 2400 also checked. I want to unchecked them